# Can I change the age to 18+ for the App Store?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Is there a way to submit an app to the App Store where the age will be 18+? The App Store currently says 12+ but we would only like 18+ using the app.

Where do I configure this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over at https://appstoreconnect.apple.com you will need to fill out the age rating survey. Based on your answers the age rating will get calculated.

[image]

As far as I know the highest possible rating is `17+`, e.g.:

> Your selected app ratings is Ages 17+.

You can achieve this by selecting "unrestricted web access".

Comment: Is there any way to set 18+? We don't want to work with underage users and add specific data processing.